# Set row maximum to 1 and other values to 0

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix

```
x = array([[ 1,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 29, 11, 35],
       [18, 16, 28, 25],
       [26, 28, 53, 52]])
```

I want to get the maximum and minimum along row and column and make it 1 and rest 0. I do in the followoing way to get max and min along column:

```
getMax = np.where(x == np.amax(x, axis=0), 1, 0)
getMin = np.where(x == np.amin(x, axis=0), 1, 0)
```

upon doing it, I get:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]]) for maximum
```

and

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]]) for minimum
```

but when I do the following to get the min and max along row

```
getMax = np.where(x == np.amax(x, axis=1), 1, 0)
getMin = np.where(x == np.amin(x, axis=1), 1, 0)
```

I get this:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]]) for maximum
```

and

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]]) for minimum
```

what is wrong in the code for min and max along row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axes to be compared are not aligned in the second case, you need to ensure the dimensions of both arrays are the same. So for that you have `keepdims`, which is precisely aimed at preserving the input shape. Also there's no need for `np.where`, you can just cast to `int`:

```
(x == np.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)).view('i1')

array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Or we could use `argmax` with `np.put_along_axis` for a more performant approach:

```
getMax = np.zeros_like(x)
np.put_along_axis(getMax,x.argmax(1)[:,None],1,axis=1)
```

Timings:

```
a = np.concatenate([x]*10000, axis=0)

%timeit np.where(a == np.amax(a, axis=1, keepdims=True), 1, 0)
# 1.15 ms ± 6.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit (a == np.amax(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)).view('i1')
# 986 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
getMax = np.zeros_like(a)
np.put_along_axis(getMax,a.argmax(1)[:,None],1,axis=1)
# 436 µs ± 12.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Note that if you do not preserve the 2D shape, you'll get:

```
np.amax(x, axis=1)
#array([ 6, 35, 28, 53])
```

Which is a 1D array, and will be compared along the last axis in `x`. This becomes clear when comparing the dimensions of both arrays:

```
x.shape (2d array):                      4 x 4
np.amax(x, axis=1).shape (1d array):         4
```

Whereas you really want:

```
x.shape (2d array):                          4 x 4
np.amax(x, axis=1, keepdims=True).shape:     4 x 1
```

So that they are compared along the first axis (rows)

Comment: thanks. it works but i dont understand `you need to ensure the dimensions of both arrays are the same`. Could you please explain?

Comment: Sure, let me add some details @lalu

Comment: More on indexing @lalu https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d

Comment: More on indexing @lalu [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) or also here's a [guide you might find helpful](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d)