# How to multiply an embedding and mask with different dimensions in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, runtime-error, word-embedding

In my `forward` method, I currently have a character embedding of size `torch.Size([8,22,16])`, where 8 represents the batch size, 22 represents the maximum character length of each word in my dataset, and 16 is the hidden dimension. I also have a mask for each word's characters which signifies whether or not the character is valid, and its size is `torch.Size([8,22])`. I'm trying to use `unsqueeze()` and `view()` to no avail.

I keep getting errors like this:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (16) must match the size of tensor b (22) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

This is what my network looks like:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_outputs):
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(256, embedding_dim)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, n_outputs)

    def forward(self, chars, mask):
        chars_embeddings = self.embedding(chars)
        chars_embeddings = torch.mul(chars_embeddings, mask.unsqueeze(2))
        pool_embeddings = chars_embeddings.mean(dim=1)
        lin_out = self.linear1(pool_embeddings)
        drop_out = F.dropout(F.relu(lin_out), training=self.training)
        out = self.linear2(dropout)
        return out
```

Comment: I think I found a possible solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62875960/pytorch-multiply-two-high-dimensions-tensor-2-5-3-2-5-into-2-5-3?rq=3

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable code example?

Comment: @YakovDan resolved, i had an extra unsqueeze somewhere causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have more dimensions than you specified, judging by the error `non-singleton dimension 3` which should have been `non-singleton dimension 2` had the dimensions been as your specified. Changing `mask.unsqueeze(2)` to `mask.unsqueeze(3)` will probably fix the issue.